# Best way for a web page to occupy 100% of screen across multiple resolutions

Tags: html, css

I have a page that I want to occupy 100% of the screen.  I have tried a few methods but I always get a vertical scrollbar for some screen resolutions.  In Chrome 100vh always leaves a scrollbar.  I have to bring it down to 97vh before it disappears.  I thought about a JavaScript solution but I would like to keep it all css if possible.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="height:100vh;border:solid 1px green;">
            <h1>HI</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `100vh` leaves a scrollbar because `body` has a margin on in by default. Set `margin: 0` on `body`. Do note that `vh`-based solutions generally don't work on mobile devices. We've god many questions about this behavior. If you've looked at those, please mention them in your question and how the answers didn't work, so that we don't end up telling you the same thing again.

Comment: I forgot that the body had a margin.  That helped a lot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to hide the scrollbar then you can try the following code in CSS styling-

```
body::webkit-scrollbar{display:none;}
```

but if you want no scrolling such that only this  would be 100% occupying the page such that there would be no further scrolling then specify the following in CSS code-

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css, body::webkit-scrollbar{display:none;}. This way the scrollbar will be hidden but you can still scroll

Comment: It's important that the content be 100% without scrolling.

Comment: Then use, body{overflow:hidden;}. This way scrollbar will neither be visible nor it will work.